# Increase the maxRequestLength/executionTimeout of a ServiceHost in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, servicehost

I have a winForms application running on a server and I access it from another application via a Service which is running over a `ServiceHost`.

The problem is, when the data which the client wants to get from the `ServiceHost` is to big I get a exception like:

> Error while receiving, the reason could be not using a http-protocol.

How can I solve this? Would this be a web application I simply would increase the maxRequestLength/executionTimeout in the web.config. but there is no web.config in a winforms project.

EDIT: here is some code:

```
Service s = new Service(this.foo);
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(s, baseAddress);
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new BasicHttpBinding(), "");
host.Open();
```

Comment: You didn't quote the exception message accurately.  Document your question better by also enabling logging: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the binding (in your example BasicHttpBinding) just set its MaxReceivedMessageSize (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.servicemodel.httpbindingbase.maxreceivedmessagesize.aspx) to the value appropriate for your scenario.

```
    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding { MaxReceivedMessageSize = 20000; };
```

Comment: I just noticed, that I havn't read the exception message you provided. It states that you were possibly not using a HTTP protocol while specifying a HTTP Binding. What is the address of the service?

Comment: its a http adress. and its working for a limit of <3000 elements. when i get more, i get the exception

Comment: The problem is that your exception is just a genaral one. So it's hard to say what exactly causes the error. As far as I understood your scenario, you have a WCF service hosted inside a Windows Forms app and a client application accessing the service. Make sure you use the same binding configuration on both sides (especially with the MaxReceivedMessageSize property). You may also add a system.servicemodel section to your app.config and add configuration data for your service there. Afterwards it'll be easier to use the same configuration on the client.